# How can I get current location lattitude and longitude in marshmallow and later versions?

Tags: android, location, android-6.0-marshmallow

1. First I want to check Internet connection is connected or not .if not connected then show dilog box for start Internet connection.
2. Then I want to check GPS is on or not if on then get latitude and longitude location and show the latitude and longitude in text or in Toast.
3. In My Code I have Used GPS Tracker to get location.

   ```
   public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {
       private final Context mContext;
       // flag for GPS status
       boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
       // flag for network status
       boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
       // flag for GPS status
       boolean canGetLocation = false;
       Location location; // location
       double latitude; // latitude
       double longitude; // longitude
       // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
       private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters
       // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
       private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute
       // Declaring a Location Manager
       protected LocationManager locationManager;
       public GPSTracker(Context context) {
           this.mContext = context;
           getLocation();
       }
       public Location getLocation() {
           try {
               locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                       .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
               // getting GPS status
               isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                       .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
               // getting network status
               isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                       .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
               if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                   // no network provider is enabled
               } else {
                   this.canGetLocation = true;
                   // First get location from Network Provider
                   if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                       locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                               LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                               MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                               MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                       Log.d("Network", "Network");
                       if (locationManager != null) {
                           location = locationManager
                                   .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                           if (location != null) {
                               latitude = location.getLatitude();
                               longitude = location.getLongitude();
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                   if (isGPSEnabled) {
                       if (location == null) {
                           locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                   LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                   MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                   MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                           Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                           if (locationManager != null) {
                               location = locationManager
                                       .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                               if (location != null) {
                                   latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                   longitude = location.getLongitude();
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return location;
       }
       /**
        * Stop using GPS listener
        * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
        */
       public void stopUsingGPS() {
           if (locationManager != null) {
               locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
           }
       }
       /**
        * Function to get latitude
        */
       public double getLatitude() {
           if (location != null) {
               latitude = location.getLatitude();
           }
           // return latitude
           return latitude;
       }
       /**
        * Function to get longitude
        */
       public double getLongitude() {
           if (location != null) {
               longitude = location.getLongitude();
           }
           // return longitude
           return longitude;
       }
       /**
        * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
        *
        * @return boolean
        */
       public boolean canGetLocation() {
           return this.canGetLocation;
       }
       /**
        * Function to show settings alert dialog
        * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
        */
       public void showSettingsAlert() {
           AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
           // Setting Dialog Title
           alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Setting");
           // Setting Dialog Message
           alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
           // On pressing Settings button
           alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                   mContext.startActivity(intent);
               }
           });
           // on pressing cancel button
           alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
           // Showing Alert Message
           alertDialog.show();
       }
       @Override
       public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       }
       @Override
       public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
       }
       @Override
       public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
       }
       @Override
       public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
       }
       @Override
       public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```
4. `Main Activity` `onCreate` I have used below code to get location in latitude and longitude

   ```
   GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
   if (gpsTracker.canGetLocation()) {
       CurrentLattitude = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
       CurrentLongitude = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
       Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(CurrentLattitude));
       Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(CurrentLongitude));
   } else {
       gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert();
   }
   ```
5. I am getting location in and able to see in Logcat when runs on kitkat but when same code I am using in marshmallow it will gives below:

   ```
   E/latlang: 0.0
   E/latlang: 0.0
   ```

How can I get the latitude and the longitude in marshmallow?

Comment: Use runtime permission and `FusedLocationProviderAPI`

Comment: Show your code bro..

Comment: my question is very simple.. how to check the permission in marshmallow in kitkat i am getting result which i want.. but don't know how to give permission for marshmallow because its only not giving me result in marshmallow

Comment: @piyush please tell me how to use runtime permission ..

Answer (score 1):

```
// getting GPS status
isGPSEnabled = locationManager
    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

// getting network status
isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking internet connection:

```
private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
    final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
    final Field connectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
    connectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
    final Object connectivityManager = connectivityManagerField.get(conman);
    final Class connectivityManagerClass =  Class.forName(connectivityManager.getClass().getName());
    final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = connectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);

    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(connectivityManager, enabled);
}
```